# position: absolute only working on the first item

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a user card where there's a menu button on the top of the card when clicked, it should show a menu. Whenever I click on the menu of the first item in the loop, then it shows fine. However, there are many user cards and when I click on the menu button of the other cards, the menu still shows on the first card and not on the card that I click. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<template>
<div class="custom-users" v-if="users && users.length > 0">
      <user-card
        v-for="user in users"
        :key="user.userId"
        @open-menu="openMenu"
      >
      </user-card>
      <div class="menu" v-if="showMenu">
          <p>Delete</p>
      </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
  data() {
    return {
       showMenu: false,
    };
  },
   methods: {
    openMenu(){
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
    },
}
}
</script>
<style scoped>

.custom-users{
  position: relative;
}
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 60px;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned absolutely *relative* to their most recent parent that has `position: relative` on it (or `position: absolute` as well).

You need to put both elements inside a container that has `position: relative` so that the dropdown will be positioned relative to the card, not to the whole container.

Comment: I've placed the menu inside the user-card but now the card doesn't show at all. I've added a conole log in the openMenu method and whenever I click on the menu icon, the console log is fine but the menu isn't shown.. I've a class to the user-card and position relative for the card

Comment: Is your card styled with `position: relative` ? (it should be) and does your card have `overflow:hidden` set on it? (It shouldn't) and are the classes getting properly applied to your new menu nested in the card?

Comment: There's no overflow: hidden. Now it shows the menu when I added the slot="content" in the menu div. but now it shows the menu for all the cards whenever I click on the menu icon of any card

Answer (score 0):

The menu is currently positioned relative to `custom-users`, which is common to all `<user-card>`. It simply looks like it's associated with the first `<user-card>` because they both are aligned to the top left (in normal flow).

Move the menu

```
<div class="menu" v-if="showMenu">
   <p>Delete</p>
</div>
```

Inside the `<user-card>` component, apply `position: relative;` to it's top most element and make the below state and method part of `<user-card>` as well.

```
data() {
  return {
       showMenu: false,
    };
  },
methods: {
   openMenu(){
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
   },
}
```

This won't be a big problem for now since menu is only created conditionally. If menu turns out to be a large component on it's own, you can give it the ability to be displayed at coordinates passed in as props in future.

Comment: I've placed the menu inside the user-card but now the card doesn't show at all. I've added a conole log in the openMenu method and whenever I click on the menu icon, the console log is fine but the menu isn't shown.. I've a class to the user-card and position relative for the card

Comment: That will be a problem since in house library. However, now the menu shows up when I added slot="content" to the div menu. apparently something inside the card can only be shown with that slot. but now the problem is that when I click on one card, the menu displays on all the cards

Comment: *"menu displays on all the cards"* sounds like each component doesn't have it's own state (data)?

Comment: I do send some data from the parent component to the user-card like username, created_at but didn't write it down here since it seemed unnecessary. However, the parent component has data like the showMenu which gets toggled on each click

Comment: *"However, the parent component has data like the showMenu which gets toggled on each click"* - I wrote in the answer, this should be inside each card, not shared, since each card controls it's own menu

Comment: that user-card component I get from a library though. I'm not sure how I can declare data inside the component of a library. All I know is I send props or slots

Comment: I see... looks like you need to either wrap each card in your own component like `my-user-card` with state, or make the common parents state a map like `{ "user-card-id-1": false,  "user-card-id-2": true, "user-card-id-3": false,}` and so on

Comment: there's gonna be millions of users, not sure if the map thing is viable. what i'm not understanding is why adding a class to user-card not working with position: relative and then doing something like `<user-card class="usr-class"><div class="menu"></div></user-card>`. I'm not sure why I need to even add slot='content' to display the menu